# How to properly type javascript codes in NetBeans 7.4?

Tags: java, javascript, php, html, netbeans

I am using netbeans 7.4 which supports HTML & PHP only. I have a javascript tutorial and I need to practice those codes in an IDE. (I am absolutely new to javascript). I created a new project (Project type is HTML5, not PHP). Then under source files I created a new javascript file. Then I started my coding.Errors are not shown in my codes when I type something wrong. I intentionally typed some code (dfd.rt())which does not exist at all, but no error is shown. Why is that? In addition I cannot see that much of good intellisense in my javascript files whereas I could get a lot of assistance from the IDE when I typed PHP codes. For examples in PHP when I type ec, IDE showed me echo, but in JS nothing is shown when I type document for doucment.write(). 
I feel that I am not using javascript files correctly in the IDE.
Can anybody show me correct steps to create a javascript project and type proper javascript codes in netbeans which will underline error codes in red and provide good support in intellisense

P:S - I searched in SO and found out some plugin needs to be installed, but I guess I have already necessary stuff installed. That is why they showed me javascript templates under source files. Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans has a plugin for JSLint - Which technically is a code quality tool not a debugger but I find it very useful for JS. It will show you probably more errors and code quality suggestions than you'll need but you can configure it to your taste. check it out. http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40893/jslint